# Why FULLCALENDAR not showing events after 13:00 (1:00pm)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Calendar renders events before **13:00 (1:00pm)**

```js
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    timeZone: 'local',
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    eventColor: '#c1c1c1',
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    initialDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '18:00:00',
    selectable: true,
    locales: 'ru',
    duration: { days: 1 },
    slotLabelFormat: {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        omitZeroMinute: false,
        meridiem: 'short'
    },
  });
```

what's the problem, maybe in timeZone?

Comment: If you could share any fiddle link which reproduce your issue would be nice.

Comment: Edit this one, save it, and post a link. http://jsfiddle.net/a7mad24/jso51pm6/ It might take you less than a minute.

Comment: Thank you all, I found my mistake. There was  `moment(value.start_date + " " + value.start_min).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');` on `addEvent` method

Comment: I changed time format from `hh:mm` to `HH:mm`